# Issues with rewriting urls using htaccess

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite some URLs using htaccess, there is something strange I can't understand.

here is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^category/(\d+)$  category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

the actual link in Html :

```
<a href='category/{$cat_id}'>{$catTitle}</a>
```

The problem:

Lets's say I am at home which is `http://localhost/CMS/` and I click on the link `http://localhost/CMS/category/1` it works fine but if I am at `http://localhost/CMS/category/1` and I click the same link I get `http://localhost/CMS/category/category/1` which is not a valid link why does category/ gets added instead of replaced.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's how relative URLs work. If you are viewing `http://localhost/CMS/category/1` and click on `<a href='category/{$cat_id}'>{$catTitle}</a>` then that translates to requesting a sibling named category and a child named `1`. You should use a root relative URL such as `<a href='/CMS/category/{$cat_id}'>{$catTitle}</a>`. You can also opt to define a `<base>` tag but I have a feeling that it would make things worse for you.